# Trying to update Homebrew on MacOS but got error saying "LibreSSL error"

Tags: homebrew, iterm2

I have late 2013 MacBook Pro. Very good laptop to last me long time! My software was updated to MacOS Big Sur. Anyway, I haven't updated homebrew in a while and I was trying to updated it.

However, when I typed in `brew outdated`, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    11: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
    10: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
     9: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:21:in `<module:OS>'
     4: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:58:in `prerelease?'
     3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:24:in `version'
     2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:24:in `new'
     1: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/version.rb:26:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/version.rb:368:in `initialize': Version value must be a string; got a NilClass () (TypeError)
```

and typing in `brew update` get this:

```
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I don't know what's happening and what I should do. I tried looking up the problem but some of them are outdated or confusing.

Also when I typed in `brew --version`, I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    11: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
    10: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
     9: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:21:in `<module:OS>'
     4: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:58:in `prerelease?'
     3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:24:in `version'
     2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:24:in `new'
     1: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/version.rb:26:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/version.rb:368:in `initialize': Version value must be a string; got a NilClass () (TypeError)
```

Do I uninstall and start over again? Does it has something to do with my zsh shell that I'm using as the default version in my iTerm2? Or does it has something to do with slow internet connection?

Comment: Curious what `brew --version` says, if anything.

Comment: I added it to the question above

Comment: Yeah, the fact that you can't even say `brew --version` suggests that Homebrew is hosed.

Comment: hosed? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Looks like your Homebrew installation is broken. Might need to reinstall it.

Comment: ok I uninstalled and reinstalled the homebrew and checked again for the version... I seems to be working.. I got the results saying `Homebrew 3.0.4-8-gb024954
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 25d8e2; last commit 2020-01-28)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision b7e4b; last commit 2020-01-29)`   Should I be concerned about the last two core/cask versions?